# Prettier throwing error after installing 'prettier-plugin-tailwindcss'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, mern, prettier

This is my Code:

```
import { FaX } from "react-icons/fa6";
import React from "react";
import { Task, createTask } from "../../models/tasksModel";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { createTaskFunction, updateTask } from "../../utils/fetchTasks";

interface FormModalProps {
    setShow: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    onDone: (task: Task) => void;
    taskToEdit?: Task | null;
    setTaskToEdit?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Task | null>>;
}

const FormModal = ({
    setShow,
    onDone,
    taskToEdit,
    setTaskToEdit,
}: FormModalProps) => {
    const closeModal = () => {
        setShow((prev) => !prev);
        setTaskToEdit && setTaskToEdit(null);
    };

    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        reset,
        formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    } = useForm<createTask>({
        defaultValues: {
            title: taskToEdit?.title || "",
            description: taskToEdit?.description || "",
            isUrgent: taskToEdit?.isUrgent || false,
            isImportant: taskToEdit?.isImportant || false,
        },
    });

    const onFormSubmit = async (input: createTask) => {
        try {
            let data;
            if (taskToEdit) {
                data = await updateTask(taskToEdit._id, input);
                onDone(data.updatedTask);
            } else {
                data = await createTaskFunction(input);
                onDone(data.newTask);
            }
            reset();
            setShow((prev) => !prev);
            setTaskToEdit && setTaskToEdit(null);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div
            id="modal_div"
            className="z-10 fixed inset-0 bg-slate-800 bg-opacity-50 w-screen h-screen flex flex-col p-16 max-sm:p-4"
        >
            <div
                id="container_div"
                className="relative w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center"
            >
                <div
                    className="flex justify-end relative w-full"
                    id="close_div"
                >
                    <FaX
                        className="text-white cursor-pointer"
                        onClick={closeModal}
                        size={50}
                    />
                </div>
                <div
                    id="form_div"
                    className="bg-white p-4 relative w-1/2 max-sm:w-full rounded-lg my-auto"
                >
                    <form
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}
                        className="flex flex-col gap-4 text-black"
                    >
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Title"
                                id="title"
                                className="focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-0 shadow-inner border-2 border-slate-300 relative w-full p-2 rounded-md"
                                {...register("title", {
                                    required: "Title is required",
                                })}
                            />
                            {errors.title && (
                                <p className="text-red-500 text-sm">
                                    {errors.title.message}
                                </p>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <textarea
                                cols={40}
                                rows={5}
                                id="description"
                                placeholder="Description"
                                className="focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-0 shadow-inner border-2 border-slate-300 relative w-full p-2 rounded-md"
                                {...register("description")}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div
                            id="checkbox_div"
                            className="flex text-slate-600 max-sm:flex-col max-sm:gap-4 gap-12"
                        >
                            <div
                                id="urgent_div"
                                className="flex gap-2 justify-between items-baseline max-sm:w-3/5"
                            >
                                <label htmlFor="isUrgent">
                                    This task is urgent
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    placeholder="Description"
                                    id="isUrgent"
                                    className="w-5 h-5 cursor-pointer accent-green-500"
                                    {...register("isUrgent")}
                                    defaultChecked={false}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="important_div"
                                className="flex gap-2 justify-between items-baseline max-sm:w-3/5"
                            >
                                <label htmlFor="isImportant">
                                    This task is important
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    placeholder="Description"
                                    id="isImportant"
                                    className="w-5 h-5 cursor-pointer accent-green-500"
                                    {...register("isImportant")}
                                    defaultChecked={false}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex gap-6 justify-end max-sm:justify-center">
                            <button
                                type="reset"
                                value=""
                                className="h-8 w-32 bg-slate-400 text-white rounded-md shadow-md active:shadow-xl active:scale-50 transition duration-300 ease-in-out"
                            >
                                Reset
                            </button>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                value=""
                                className="h-8 w-32 bg-green-500 text-white rounded-md shadow-md active:shadow-xl active:scale-50 transition duration-300 ease-in-out"
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                            >
                                Done
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FormModal;
```

It was working fine till I installed prettier-plugin-tailwindcss package, now prettier is giving an error :

```
["ERROR" - 9:54:08 AM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 9:54:08 AM] '>' expected. (59:13)
  57 |     return (
  58 |         <div
> 59 |             id="modal_div"
     |             ^
  60 |             className="z-10 fixed inset-0 bg-slate-800 bg-opacity-50 w-screen h-screen flex flex-col p-16 max-sm:p-4"
  61 |         >
  62 |             <div
SyntaxError: '>' expected. (59:13)
  57 |     return (
  58 |         <div
> 59 |             id="modal_div"
     |             ^
  60 |             className="z-10 fixed inset-0 bg-slate-800 bg-opacity-50 w-screen h-screen flex flex-col p-16 max-sm:p-4"
  61 |         >
  62 |             <div
    at Kq (file:///D:/Documents/Codes/Projects/mern_typescript/client/node_modules/.pnpm/prettier@3.2.5/node_modules/prettier/plugins/typescript.mjs:23:498)
    at xz (file:///D:/Documents/Codes/Projects/mern_typescript/client/node_modules/.pnpm/prettier@3.2.5/node_modules/prettier/plugins/typescript.mjs:25:794)
    at Object.Cz [as parse] (file:///D:/Documents/Codes/Projects/mern_typescript/client/node_modules/.pnpm/prettier@3.2.5/node_modules/prettier/plugins/typescript.mjs:25:1194)
    at parse4 (file:///D:/Documents/Codes/Projects/mern_typescript/client/node_modules/.pnpm/prettier@3.2.5/node_modules/prettier/index.mjs:22117:24)
    at async coreFormat (file:///D:/Documents/Codes/Projects/mern_typescript/client/node_modules/.pnpm/prettier@3.2.5/node_modules/prettier/index.mjs:22607:7)
    at async formatWithCursor (file:///D:/Documents/Codes/Projects/mern_typescript/client/node_modules/.pnpm/prettier@3.2.5/node_modules/prettier/index.mjs:22809:14)
    at async Module.format2 (file:///D:/Documents/Codes/Projects/mern_typescript/client/node_modules/.pnpm/prettier@3.2.5/node_modules/prettier/index.mjs:24194:25)
["INFO" - 9:54:08 AM] Formatting completed in 562ms.
```

This is my prettierrc file:

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "singleAttributePerLine": false,
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "filepath": "d:\\Documents\\Codes\\Projects\\mern_typescript\\client\\src\\models\\tasksModel.ts",
  "parser": "typescript"
}
```

I also have ther prettier extension in my VS Code
Why am I getting this error? How can I solve it?

I tried changing the `"jsxBracketSameLine": true` (it was originally set to `false`). It still did not work. Has anyone faced this type of problem before? How did you solve it?